# Vim tip: Esc is really far away for my pinky, I have short pinkies, don't hate. Here's what to do

Tags: vim, macvim

They say anything you can do from the center of the keyboard is fastest and most efficient. I think Esc is pretty damn far for my pinky to stretch. What should I do?

Comment: I always use the middle finger to press escape. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several options: You can alternatively press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>, which is equivalent to <kbd>Esc</kbd>. You can define a mapping, e.g. `jj`, or `jk` and `kj`. Or you remap another convenient key (Caps Lock, Ctrl), to Esc. You'll find a lenghty discussion at [Avoid the escape key](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key) on the Vim Tips Wiki.

I recommend mapping the conveniently located, but seldomly used <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd>. It is described in [Map caps lock to escape in Windows](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_caps_lock_to_escape_in_Windows) and [Map caps lock to escape in XWindows](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_caps_lock_to_escape_in_XWindows).

Comment: Hahaha, there's a whole page on the wiki dedicated to this! ...What's great about remapping capslock is you avoid capslock disasters in vim too. I tried this but eventually lost of a sense of capslock vs tab for whatever strange reason.

Comment: I cannot help but notice that ctrl+[ is ergonomically just as bad, if not worse, for _both_ pinkies...

Answer (score 4):

So the English language has very few occurrences of two j's in a row. In fact here's all of them: hajj, hajjes, hajji, hajjis. Seems to be really common for guys named Hajj or people who've done a pilgrimage to Mecca. But for those of us with no friends name Hajj, or trips to Mecca jj makes for a really great shortcut for Esc in vim.

I especially love this remap because it saves me those times when I don't realize I'm in insert mode : ( j'ing around like I'm trying to scroll, meanwhile there's a nice string of j's accumulating inside a function somewhere. The worst is when someone leaves your capslock on. Then you have no idea why your code is erupting!

I've also remapped kk to Esc, but the cost is a bit higher. Again here are English words with double k's (lots more than double j's):

bookkeeper
bookkeepers
bookkeeping
bookkeepings
chukka
chukkar
chukkars
chukkas
chukker
chukkers
dekko
dekkos
hokku
jackknife
jackknifed
jackknifes
jackknifing
jackknives
knickknack
knickknacks
lockkeeper
lockkeepers
markka
markkaa
markkas
pukka
quokka
quokkas
shikker
shikkers
stockkeeper
stockkeepers
sukkah
sukkahs
sukkot
sukkoth
trekked
trekker
trekkers
trekking
yakked
yakker
yakkers
yakking
yukked
yukking
zikkurat
zikkurats

And lastly, here's the code to for those remappings (just drop those two lines in your .vimrc file in your home directly, should work as long as there are no conflicts, you may need to create this file if you haven't already.):

```
inoremap jj <Esc>
inoremap kk <Esc>
```

Comment: That's a nifty trick that I never would have even thought was possible.  I use my middle finger to press escape.  It may seem like it's farther away than the pinky, but it's also significantly longer, so I can hit escape and get back to the home row pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest mapping Caps Lock to Esc when pressed by itself, and mapped to Ctrl when pressed in any combination of keys.

Comment: Cool, how do you do that?

Comment: I am on Win7 and use Autohotkey.  It means you can use it across any software.  It is v. handy.